# Compare two array and return result in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array, $arr1 and $arr2 which looks as follows when print it in print_r

```
print_r(arr1)
```

gives

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
                   [state_id] => 1 
                   [state_name] => Gujrat 
               )
        [1] => Array ( 
                   [state_id] => 2 
                   [state_name] => Maharashtra 
               )
      )
```

My 2nd array

```
print_r($arr2)
```

gives

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
                   [state] => 1 
               ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
                   [state] => 2)
               )
      )
```

when i use

```
$result=array_intersect($arr1,$arr2);
print_r($result);
```

It Gives me error `Array to string conversion`

I want resulting array as if values matched

```
 Array ( 
         [0] => Array ( 
                    [state_id] => 1 
                    [state_name] => Gujrat 
                ) 
         [1] => Array ( 
                    [state_id] => 2 
                    [state_name] => Maharashtra 
                )
       )
```

how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

`array_intersect()` assumes the arrays contain scalars, but in your case they are arrays, hence the error.

```
// Extract state IDs from $arr2 into $states:
$states = [];
foreach ( $arr2 as $a ) {
  $states[ $a['state' ] ] = TRUE;
}

// Create $result by copying all elements from $arr1 into $result
// which have a state ID that we want:
$result = []; // New array
foreach ( $arr1 as $k => $v ) {
  if ( $states[ $v['state_id' ] ] ) { // We want this state
    $result[] = $v;
  }
}
```